# Affine Tranformation Matrix; shapely asks 6 coefficients, but rasterio delivers 9; how to translate

Tags: line, shapely, rasterio, linestring, affine-transformation

Some lines have been extracted via scikit-image, now tho goal is to vectorize them within the origin coordinate reference system

```py
#some geotif opened with rasterio
src = rasterio.open(raster_path)
transform = src.tranform
print("transform",transform)
>> | 0.10, 0.00, 350482.83|
| 0.00,-0.10, 5617200.95|
| 0.00, 0.00, 1.00|
print("type(transform)",type(transform))
>> <class 'affine.Affine'>
#some line extract from the geotiff with scikit-image
line = ((849, 2363), (1626, 1711)) 
#extract start- and end-pointof line
p0, p1 = line
# construct points in shapely
A = Point(p0[0],p0[1])
B = Point(p1[0],p1[1])
AB = LineString([A, B])
print("AB",AB)
>> LINESTRING (849 2363, 1626 1711)
AB = affine_transform(AB, transform)
>>ValueError: 'matrix' expects either 6 or 12 coefficients
```

How does one get a 6 coefficient Matrix or a 12 coefficient Matrix from from a geotiff with `rasterio`?

or

How does one translate an 9 coefficient affine transformation to a 6 coefficient one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A 9 coefficient transform matrix has each 3 coefficients, each corresponding to the 3 spacial dimensions.
Shapely expects a coefficient matrix for data with 2 spatial dimensions.
Hence a selection has to be performed.

beware these are right coefficients, albeit in the wrong order:

```py
[*transform[0:3],*transform[3:6]]
>>[0.10000036968576852, 0.0, 350482.8259, 0.0, -0.1000006060605726, 5617200.9533]
```

rather extract them with the Affine Object native function `.column_vectors` and unpack to tuples to a list to obtain the correct order:

```py
coef_6_transform = [element for tupl in transform.column_vectors for element in tupl]
>> [0.10000036968576852, 0.0, 0.0, -0.1000006060605726, 350482.8259, 5617200.9533]
AB = affine_transform(AB, coef_6_transform))
```

This worked fine and yielded the lines on the right position

Answer (score 0):

`rasterio.affine.Affine` has a `to_shapely` method to do just that:

```
shapely.affinity.affine_transform(geom, rio_affine.to_shapely())
```

Unfortunately, you won't find anything about `to_shapely` in `rasterio`'s documentation, presumably because although maintained by the rasterio's team, it is technically part of a stand-alone [`affine` python library](https://pypi.org/project/affine/), the documentation of which is, AFAICS, missing.